# How to compare an escape sequence with a constant string?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome-terminal, escape-characters

I wanted to do a thing conditionally based on the background colour of my terminal, which I found out can be grasped by running

```
printf '\e]11;?\a'
```

In my case the output is

```
stanton@mybox:~$ printf '\e]11;?\a'
^[]11;rgb:ffff/ffff/ffff^Gstanton@mybox:~$ 11;rgb:ffff/ffff/ffff
```

which is already confusing. Anyway, I thought of running a test like

```
[ "$(printf '\e]11;?\a')" = "^[]11;rgb:ffff/ffff/ffff^G" ] && echo it\'s light || echo it\'s dark
```

but it doesn't work. (I've tried any possible variation of the string that came to my mind, with or without the escape sequences, etc., to no result.)

What do I have to do to compare the output of printf and a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do not want the output of `printf`, but rather the reply from the terminal. Your `$(...)` does not evaluate to this reply, as we can see:

```
$ v=$(printf '\e]11;?\a')
$ printf "%q\n" "$v"
$'\E]11;?\a'
```

The variable v is the same as the output of the first printf (the $'...' is the result of the format `%q` which quotes the string).

You need to use the shell's `read` command to capture the reply from the terminal. For example, with bash:

```
$ read  -n 24 -p "$v"  reply
$ printf "%q\n" "$reply"
$'\E]11;rgb:ffff/ffff/ffff\a'
```

Here `-p` is used to print the variable `$v`, and the variable `reply` reads 24 characters from the terminal response. The final printf shows that `reply` holds the string you expected. So you can compare with it:

```
[ "$reply" = $'\e]11;rgb:ffff/ffff/ffff\a' ]
```

Comment: Note not all terminal emulators react to what `printf '\e]11;?\a'` prints. The whole approach depends on the terminal emulator in use, this is rather peculiar. In addition I would call your answer a *hack* with `read -p`. I wonder if (fast enough, unfortunately timed) input from keyboard may interfere. Still your answer is interesting; I didn't know one can (ab)use `read` like this.

Comment: I agree, it would be wiser to do this from a C program, or perl etc. The hack can be made a little more robust by adding to the `read` the raw flag `-r`, a nul char delimter with `-d ''` and a timeout with `-t`, but it will never be perfect.